# How to disable a script with void OnTriggerEnter2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this script that disables my movement when I enter a certain area, how do I make my animation go from whatever animation they are in to my idle animation only when I enter the collider? Thanks!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class endLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

     

        GetComponent<CharacterController2d>().enabled = false;
        Debug.Log("Level Cleared");

    }
}
```

Comment: The same way but via an `Animator` component? E.g. via [`SetTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify that object is Player

first set your player Object Tag or Layer
set to "Player" and go to your script

```
if(collision.CompareTag("Player"))
```

or

```
int PlayerLayer;
void Start()
PlayerLayer = layer.NametoLayer("Player")

if(collision.gameObject.layer == PlayerLayer)
```

if collided gameObject is player. get player script's Animator to stop function.

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

"[...] make my animation go from whatever animation they are in to my idle animation only when I enter the collider[...]"

Use [Animator.CrossFade](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.CrossFade.html). Example:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    GetComponent<Animator>().CrossFade("your_idle_state", 0.5f);
}
```

For performance reasons, I recommend caching the Animator reference in a private variable, initialized in `Start()`. If you are unsure if the object actually has an Animator Component, use [TryGetComponent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html).